# How to start tmux from script-wrapper

Tags: zsh, tmux, i3

I have

```
# dotfiles/bin/withtmux.sh
#!/bin/sh

exec tmux
```

And I want to

```
# i3config
# start terminal without tmux, plain zsh, work
bindsym $mod+e exec $terminal

# and with tmux, not working
bindsym $mod+Shift+e exec $terminal -e ~/.config/dotfiles/bin/withtmux.sh
```

Comment: I have no idea what it is you are trying to do, but your Zsh environment is populated from `.zshenv`, not `.zshrc`.

Comment: I have renamed question

Comment: Renaming it doesn't describe any better the actual problem...

Comment: @jasonwryan I have edited question too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In script file (script.sh)

```
<terminal> -e tmux
```

eg: terminator -e tmux

in i3 config file
`bindsym $mod+Shift+e exec 'bash path_to_script/script.sh'`

Answer (score 0):

You could try using ~/.zshenv

The shell reads ~/.zshenv first; if a login shell is used, ~/.zprofile is then read; if an interactive shell is used, commands are read from ~/.zshrc. Finally, if it is a login shell, ~/.zlogin is parsed.

See the STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES section of `man zsh` for more on this.

Comment: But If I specify ZSH_TMUX_AUTOSTART in zshenv - that will affect to bindsym $mod+e exec $terminal
P.S. have renamed question